# "Un-associate" socket from completion port

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock, iocp

`CreateIoCompletionPort()` is used to associate a socket with a completion port. However, when this socket is closed, then I need to "un-associate" it from the completion port. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A handle that is associated with an I/O Completion Port is removed from the port when the handle is closed. In case of a network socket, the handle is closed by calling [`closesocket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582.aspx).

The documentation for [CreateIoCompletionPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862.aspx) contains remarks on resource handling:

> The handle passed in the FileHandle parameter can be any handle that supports overlapped I/O. Most commonly, this is a handle opened by the [**CreateFile**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) function using the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag (for example, files, mail slots, and pipes). **Objects created by other functions such as [socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506.aspx) can also be associated with an I/O completion port**. For an example using sockets, see [**AcceptEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524.aspx). A handle can be associated with only one I/O completion port, and after the association is made, **the handle remains associated with that I/O completion port until it is closed**.
>
> ...
>
> The I/O completion port handle and every file handle associated with that particular I/O completion port are known as *references to the I/O completion port*. The I/O completion port is released when there are no more references to it. Therefore, all of these **handles must be properly closed to release the I/O completion port** and its associated system resources. After these conditions are satisfied, close the I/O completion port handle by calling the [**CloseHandle**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx) function.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft obviously doesn’t want ordinary users to do it, but nonetheless, there is an officially documented way (and it only required a madton of digging to find it):

Calling [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the value `FileReplaceCompletionInformation` for the `FileInformationClass` parameter, will get it done. (This value is defined in [`FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff728840(v=vs.85).aspx))

A copy of the description for this parameter value (emphasis mine):

> Change or remove the I/O completion port for the specified file handle.
>   The caller supplies a pointer to a FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION structure 
>   that specifies a port handle and a completion key. If the port handle is 
>   non-NULL, this handle specifies a new I/O completion port to associate with 
>   the file handle. **To remove the I/O completion port associated with the
>   file handle, set the port handle in the structure to NULL.**
>   To get a port handle, a user-mode caller can call the CreateIoCompletionPort function.

Comment: Good find, but note that FileReplaceCompletionInformation is only available starting with Windows 8.1